# Synchronize throttling

Tags: ros, syncronization, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the throttle node under topic_tools support synchronized
throttling? I have a stereo camera and I'm logging left/image_rect,
right/image_rect and the relevant camera info topics. Is there an
easy way to log at a slower rate and keep all the messages in sync?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9053/synchronize-throttling/) by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately topic_tools does not support synchronized throttling. Can you open a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket) to make sure this gets tracked?

I don't have an easier solution for you than hand-rolling a node to subscribe to the four topics, synchronized, and republish them at a slower rate.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-14**:
Just to save you a tiny bit of rewrite time, if you look in
https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/grasp_playpen/src
I do the same thing (subscribe, synchronize, republish) for the PR2's
narrow and wide stereo cameras in throttle_stereo.cpp .  I also wrote
a modified version of rxbag's recorder.py that does throttled
recording of a list of topics at different rates from (Python) code,
which is in grasp_playpen/src/grasp_playpen, in case that's useful to
you.